# Rake db:create error - cannot load such file -- resque/tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, resque

setting up existing apps on my new machine.

The first app (a simple one) went ok.

For the second app most things are ok but now getting

```
Rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- resque/tasks
```

when trying to run `rake db:create`

I've installed redis and I believe it is running.

How can I resolve this error?

```
Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.2.8
```

Comment: Your rails and ruby version are compatible. So after a quick thought the most trivial question comes that "Do you have the resque gem installed?"

Comment: any results if you prepend it with --trace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed the resque gem to fix this.